# My getLine implementation only works the first time

Tags: c, getline

I have a .txt file with three lines of text.

```
12345
67
890
```

I am trying to read each line into a character array using my getLine function, and then print out the arrays:

```
int main()
{
    char line_1[100];
    char line_2[100];
    char line_3[100];

    getLine(line_1,50);
    getLine(line_2,50);
    getLine(line_3,50);

    int c;
    int i=0;

    while((c=line_1[i++]) != EOF){
        putchar(c);
    }

    i=0;
    while((c=line_2[i++]) != EOF){
        putchar(c);
    }
    i=0;
    while((c=line_3[i++]) != EOF){
        putchar(c);
    }   
}
```

However, this outputs

```
12345
íOÌ@C@À'¡67
N¿'¡890
```

With the gibberish changing each time. My getLine implementation is as follows

```
int getLine(char line[], int size)//get a line of length size from stdin
{
    int i=0;
    int c=0;

    while(((c=getchar()) !=EOF) && (c!='\n') && i<size)
    {
        line[i++]=c;
    }

    if(c=='\n') line[i++] =c;
    line[i]='\0';
    return i;

}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: You need to terminate your strings with \0

Comment: You terminate the strings with '\0' in getLine, yet you check for EOF in main(). In main you should check for the actual terminating character ('\0'), rather than the EOF char. Checking for EOF there makes no sense.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getLine` function works correctly, but the print-loops are the cause for the garbage output.

You print the output with

```
while((c=line_1[i++]) != EOF){
    putchar(c);
}
```

but `EOF` is not a character and certainly not the string terminator.

You should change the loop to

```
while((c=line_1[i++]) != '\0'){
    putchar(c);
}
```

or

```
printf("%s", line_1);
```

or

```
fputs(line_1, stdout);
```

Comment: Or: `fputs(line_1, stdout);`

Comment: Added `fputs` as alternative